# Conditional for Nested Attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I create a conditional where if the dueler is the `current_user` then it'll list the current_user's challenges and if the dueler is `@user` then it'll list the @user's challenges?

**duels_controller**

```
def new
  @user = User.find(params[:challenge_daddy])
  @duel = Duel.new
  @duel.duelers << Dueler.new(user_id: current_user.id, user_name: current_user.name, user_last_name: current_user.last_name)
  @duel.duelers << Dueler.new(user_id: @user.id, user_name: @user.name, user_last_name: @user.last_name)
  @current_user_challenges = current_user.challenges.order(:created_at)
  @challenged_user_challenges = @user.challenges.order(:created_at)
  respond_with(@duel)
end
```

**duels/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@duel) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :duelers do |dueler| %>
    <%= render 'dueler_fields', :f => dueler %>
  <% end %>
  The loser will <%= f.text_field :consequence %>.
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**duels/_dueler_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.order(:name).map { |user| [user.full_name, user.id] }, include_blank: true, id: "change-challenge-options" %> will
<%= collection_select(:dueler, :challenge_id, # @challenged_user_challenges or @current_user_challenges
, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true) %>
```

How do I create a conditional so that if the `:user_id` is equal to the `current_user` then `@current_user_challenges` will show in `collection_select` and if `:user_id` is equal to `@user` then `@challenged_user_challenges` will show?

Comment: Can you please explain what you'r current result is and what you expect to receive?

Comment: @slowjack2k I want to list the challenges for that respective `:user_id`. How do I create a conditional so that if the `:user_id` is equal to the `current_user` then `@current_user_challenges` will show and if `:user_id` is equal to `@user` then `@challenged_user_challenges` will show.

Comment: `@challenged_user_challenges`  always contains the challenges you are looking for. When `current_user == @user` then `@challenged_user_challenges == @current_user_challenges`. With the given code I see no need for an `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some java/coffee script to do this, since it means real time changes to the form.

Add current user to data and a partial (or two different collection_selects with ids):

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.order(:name).map { |user| [user.full_name, user.id] }, include_blank: true, id: "change-challenge-options", data: {current-user-id: current_user.id } %>
```

Add app/assets/javascripts/challengers.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
  userSelect = $('#change-challenge-options')
  userSelect.on 'valuesChanged', ->
    currentUserId = $('#current-challenge-options').data('current-user-id')
    if(currentUserId == userSelect.val())
      ... show / hide the correct fields
    else
      ... show / hide the correct fields
    $(window).resize            #Not necessary but makes it look nicer if the lists are long.
```

Don't know if this is the best solution but I've done something similar in my project and it works fine.

EDIT:
So firstly you'll need to add collection_select fields for both situations to your view, and supply them with ids:

```
<%= collection_select(:dueler, :challenge_id, @current_user_challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true), id: "current-user-challenges" %>
<%= collection_select(:dueler, :challenge_id, @challenged_user_challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true), id: "challenged-user-challenges" %>
```

Then in the script you need to add:

```
if(currentUserId == userSelect.val())
   $('#current-user-challenges').show()
   $('#challenged-user-challenges').hide()
else
   $('#challenged-user-challenges').show()
   $('#current-user-challenges').hide()
```

This will show/hide the correct fields. I'm not exactly sure on how to add ids to collection_selects, but if my proposal doesn't work just place them in a div or other container. Give those containers ids and show/hide them in the same way.

In addition to this you might want to add some script covering first time visits or revisits of the form properly. So the full code would be something like:

```
#page:load just makes sure the page is fully loaded before running script.
#Usefull if you use turbolinks etc.
$(document).on 'ready page:load' ->
  userSelect = $('#change-challenge-options')
  currentUserId = $('#current-challenge-options').data('current-user-id')
  $(window).on 'page:change', ->
    if(userSelect.val()) #All none zero values are true in js
      if(currentUserId == userSelect.val()) #Show the right field
        $('#current-user-challenges').show()
        $('#challenged-user-challenges').hide()
      else
        $('#challenged-user-challenges').show()
        $('#current-user-challenges').hide()
    else                                    #Hide both fields if no user is chosen.
      $('#challenged-user-challenges').hide()
      $('#current-user-challenges').hide()
    $(window).resize
  userSelect.on 'valuesChanged', ->
    if(currentUserId == userSelect.val())
      $('#current-user-challenges').show()
      $('#challenged-user-challenges').hide()
    else
      $('#challenged-user-challenges').show()
      $('#current-user-challenges').hide()
    $(window).resize
```

I hope it will work for you!

Here's a working snippet of the concept using javascript instead of coffee and raw html:

```js
var userSelect = $('#change-challenge-options');
var currentUserId = $('#current-user-id').data('user-id');
$('#challenged-user-challenges').hide();
$('#current-user-challenges').hide();
userSelect.on('change', function() {
  if (userSelect.val() == "0"){
     $('#current-user-challenges').hide();
     $('#challenged-user-challenges').hide();
    }
  else if (userSelect.val() == currentUserId) {
    $('#current-user-challenges').show();
    $('#challenged-user-challenges').hide();
  } else {
    $('#challenged-user-challenges').show();
    $('#current-user-challenges').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form id="new_challenge" role="form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div class="form-group" id="current-user-id" data-user-id = "1">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">User:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="users" id="change-challenge-options">
      <option selected="selected" value="0">Choose user...</option>
      <option value="1">Me</option>
      <option value="2">Other user</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Challenges:</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="users" id="current-user-challenges">
      <option selected="selected" value="0">Choose challenge...</option>
      <option value="1">My challenge 1</option>
      <option value="2">My challenge 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="users" id="challenged-user-challenges">
      <option selected="selected" value="0">Choose challenge...</option>
      <option value="1">Other user challenge 1</option>
      <option value="2">Other user challenge 2</option>
      <option value="3">Other user challenge 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry would you mind supplying the specifics for "show / hide the correct fields"? I don't know javascript well :/ It would be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark it as resolved.

Comment: Hey been trying to make it work the past two hours. Thanks so much for the additional elaboration. I see you edited in the comma. It took me forever to figure that out lol but nonetheless now it loads without a problem from what I can see, but still both `collection_select`s are loading. I added the `id` within `()` and also outside it because otherwise it raised an error.

Comment: Well, I never tried the code I wrote, just kind of winged it. I will try to add a working js-fiddle.

Comment: Thank you! I like to use the latter code chunk so that when the page initially loads it only shows the one `collection_select` for each user, but I don't have `turbolinks` installed so I guess I stick with `$(document).ready ->`

Comment: It doesn't really matter then whether you use it or not in that case. I tend to add it just for good measure. I added the snippet now, so at least the fundamental ideas work! :)

Comment: Thank you! It works. Yes :) I am struggling to make it where User Name Challenge Name then User Name then Challenge Name are shown, i.e. UCUC, but right now it's rendering like UUCC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125321/discussion-between-ozgar-and-anthonygalli-com).