# hide/show different information in javascript

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I am trying to show and hide information which changes in accordance with the question it belongs to. In my code, however, no matter which question is selected, the infromation in the first question shows or respectively hides.
Any ideas how can that be fixed?

Javascript:

```
function displayQuestion(answer) {
    document.getElementById(answer + 'Question').style.display = "block";

    if (answer == "yes") {
        document.getElementById('noQuestion').style.display = "none";
    } else if (answer == "no") {
        document.getElementById('yesQuestion').style.display = "none"; 
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>1. Would you like to improve financial structure?</p>
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="yes" name="yesOrNo" value="yes" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />
    Yes, i am interested
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="no" name="yesOrNo" value="no" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />
    No, hide the info
</label>
<br>
<div id="yesQuestion" style="display:none;">
    <br/>
    <p> Financial Info </p>
    <button onclick="window.location.href='fin.html'">
        Continue
    </button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="noQuestion" style="display:none;">
    <br/>
</div>
</br>

<p>2. Would you like to improve your production? </p>
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="yes" name="yesOrNo" value="yes" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />
    Yes, i am interested
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="no" name="yesOrNo" value="no" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />
    No, hide the info
</label>

<div id="yesQuestion" style="display:none;">
    <br/>
    <p> Production Info </p>
    <button onclick="window.location.href='prod.html'">
        Continue
    </button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="noQuestion" style="display:none;">
    <br/>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the event triggered to call your `displayQuestion` function? If this is all your code, you are missing a trigger for the field. I answered a similar question a few days ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39917057/5897779).

Comment: Can you use Jquery? I can provide a easy solution if so.

Comment: What would be the solution with Jquery? Thnx.

Comment: You have 2 `</form>` tag closed but never opened

Comment: @Paco gave you my solution in Javascript, Let me know if you want jquery as well

Comment: @Reddy Thanks a bunch! That solved my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JavaSCript solution:**

**Problem :** You have many elements with the same `id`. Golden rule in HTML is **"Never have the same Id for multiple elements"**. Use `class` if you want them to all have same identifiers.

Also your radio buttons have same names on both the questions, **Make one question radio buttons to have the same name**. This way when you answer the second question it doesn't uncheck the first question option as it happens currently in your code.

**Solution:** Make the **`Id` unique**, This solves the problem stated `no matter which question is selected, the infromation in the first question shows or respectively hides.` I have also made sure I change the id just by prefixing the question number to the existing id's

Eg: `yesQuestion` changed to `1yesQuestion` and `2yesQuestion`

`noQuestion` changed to `1noQuestion` and `2noQuestion`

This way we have all unique ids on the elements, Another change is to pass the question number also into the `displayQuestion` function.

```
onchange="displayQuestion(this.value,1)"
```

Below is the snippet that works as you expected.

```js
function displayQuestion(answer,questionNumber) {
   
  document.getElementById(questionNumber + answer + 'Question').style.display = "block";
  
  if (answer == "yes") {

    document.getElementById(questionNumber+'noQuestion').style.display = "none";

  } else if (answer == "no") {

    document.getElementById(questionNumber+'yesQuestion').style.display = "none";

  }

}
```

```html
<p>1. Would you like to improve financial structure?</p>
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="" name="1yesOrNo" value="yes" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value,1)" />Yes, i am interested</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="" name="1yesOrNo" value="no" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value,1)" />No, hide the info</label>


<br>
<div id="1yesQuestion" style="display:none;">
  <br/>
  <p>Financial Info</p>
  <button onclick="window.location.href='fin.html'">Continue</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="1noQuestion" style="display:none;">
  <br/>

</div>
</br>

<p>2. Would you like to improve your production?</p>
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="" name="2yesOrNo" value="yes" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value,2)" />Yes, i am interested</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="" name="2yesOrNo" value="no" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value,2)" />No, hide the info</label>


<div id="2yesQuestion" style="display:none;">
  <br/>
  <p>Production Info</p>
  <button onclick="window.location.href='prod.html'">Continue</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="2noQuestion" style="display:none;">
  <br/>

</div>
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you have got multiple elements with the same ID. This is invalid HTML. Therefore

```
document.getElementById(answer + 'Question')
```

when answer = "yes" will always select the first element with the the ID "yesQuestion". It will ignore all the others with the same ID because they are considered invalid.

You need to make the IDs unique and then adjust the "value" attributes of your radio buttons accordingly, so your code will select the correct element.